# Identifying unnecessary npm packages

Tags: npm, package.json

How do I identify `npm packages` that are **not** necessary so that I can remove them from my app?

The scenario is a situation that, I don't think, is unique where the former guy who's no longer in the team put a bunch of stuff in the `package.json` file and I'm not familiar with all the packages in there. I do want the app to be as lean and clean as possible and would like to remove anything that is unnecessary. I may find out that all the packages in the `package.json` are necessary but I do want to make sure of that.

Is going through each package and learning what it does and removing it to see if anything will break my **only** option in identifying the packages that I can remove or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`npm install -g depcheck`

then:

```
depcheck
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. After doing the global install of the `depcheck` package, I run `depcheck` in the command prompt within the project root where I have the `package.json` file but I'm getting "depcheck is not recognized as an internal or external command". Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Got it to work. Cool utility! Thank you for your help!